# HTML how to open tab in a box

Tags: html

I making a webpage. The problem is I am really bad at HTML. I need to make a button that opens up the contact like on a new page I don't know how to explain really.

Right now if I click contact it leaves it on the same page with other stuff not cleared.

How would I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[EDIT]
I misunderstood. I would try showing the element in a modal. This is simple with something like Fancybox, if you're new to coding.

https://fancyapps.com/fancybox/3/

Example of how to load an element in a modal: https://fancyapps.com/fancybox/3/docs/#inline

To hide your contact div until it's clicked:

`<div style="display: none;" id="contact">Your content...</div>`

---

[ORIGINAL]
Have you tried adding a `target="_blank"` attribute to your HTML?

Eg:

```
 <a href="#contact" target="_blank">Contact</a>
```

Comment: Hello, thank you for your answer. Fancy Box seems to work

Comment: but the contact is still showing without clicking anything is there a way to make it disappear when not clicking contact button